# Convert Base64 String to Byte Value String in Java

Tags: java, string, binary, base64, ascii

I have a Base64 String, which is 'AAAC', which in binary is equivalent to 3 bytes (00000000 00000000 00000010).

I would like to convert 'AAAC' to a ASCII Hex Byte String to output something like '000002'.

I have tried below.

```
byte[] test = Base64.decode(data.getBytes());
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (byte b : test) {
    sb.append(String.format("%02X ", b));
}
System.out.println(sb.toString()); 
//Output: 00 00 02
```

This works, but is there a more effient way to do this?

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [`DatatypeConverter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter.html) class for this:

```
String result =
    DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(DatatypeConverter
        .parseBase64Binary("AAAC"));

System.out.println(result);
```

Prints: `000002`

Answer (score 1):

With the [Guava library](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/), this might look something like

```
BaseEncoding.base16().toUpperCase().withSeparator(" ", 2)
  .encode(BaseEncoding.base64().decode(data));
```